# Error in View : 'names' attribute [1] must be the same length as the vector [0]

Tags: r

I have a data file consists of item responses (the rightmost number represents the response frequencies)

[image]

When I tried to use the `expand.table` function in package `mirt` it gives me the following error

> Error in View : 'names' attribute [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WnCUs.png) must be the same length as the vector [0]

Could somebody help me take a look at this issue?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269). This will make it much easier for others to help you.

Comment: As per the help page for the function, its first argument requires the following: "An object of class data.frame or matrix with the unique response patterns and the number of frequencies in the rightmost column." You appear to be missing the unique response patterns.

Answer (score 0):

Your data is not a table, so I am confused by the use of `expand.table`

What is your purpose?

Probably what you need to do is separate the string by `strsplit()` or `substring()` etc. and using `table()`.